# Is the adjoint operator of an analytic semigroup's generator the generator of an analytic semigroup in its own right?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach space. The adjoint semigroup $\{T(t)^\prime:t\ge 0\}$ consisting of all adjoint operators $T(t)^\prime$ on the dual space $X^\prime$ is, in general, not strongly continuous where $\{T(t):t\ge 0\}$ is a strongly continuous semigroup on $X$.

My question: Suppose $\{T(z):z\in \Delta\}$ is a analytic semigroup on $X$.  Is $\{T(z)^\prime:z\in \Delta\}$ (consisting of all adjoint operators $T(z)^\prime$ on the dual space $X^\prime$) an analytic semigroup? If so, what would be its generator?

Comment: Have you looked at $(T(\overline{z})^{\star}$ and its generator?

Comment: @T.A.E. no. also i don't have any idea about that. One thing suppose the sector $\Delta$ is not symmetric with respect to x axis then $z \in \Delta$ but $z \ber$ may not belongs to $\Delta$.

Comment: The conjugate of the one sector about the positive real axis is another sector. Also, are you looking at bounds on the resolvent?

Comment: @T.A.E. suppose $\Delta$ ={$z \in C: \alpha < arg(Z)< \beta$} where $\alpha < 0$ and $\beta>0$ and their magnitude is not same. in that case $\Delta$ is not symmetric. I am not looking at bound on resolvent. I request you to give some reference for dual of analytic semigroup.

Comment: Ah, I reread your question. I thought you were assuming the adjoint was a $C_{0}$ semigroup. I'm not sure about the answer to this question. I tend to think you won't get what you want.